# How is "< <(...)" different from "< $(...)" in bash?

Tags: bash, while-loop, io-redirection

While writing a simple "clear target" for my LaTeX workflow I noticed a detail which I just accepted in the past.

I had a working example from a long time ago using redirection from standard input to `while` using the `find` function like this:

`while ... ; do ... done < <( find ... ... ...)`.

In my ignorance I therefore expected that:

`while ... ; do ... done < $( find ... ... ...)`

did the same thing, which is not the case.

I did some *superficial* googling, but all I found was examples without explanation. Maybe someone has a good take on this or can point me to the location where the difference is outlined?

**Minimal Example**

```
touch asdf.aux asdf.bbl asdf.idx asdf.glo

AUXFILES=(aux bbl idx glo)

for AUXFILE in "${AUXFILES[@]}"; do\
  while IFS= read -r -d '' FILE; do\
    echo "deleting ${FILE}\n";\
  done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.${AUXFILE}" -print0);\
done
```

For the gurus: please feel free to edit the title as you see fit to make it more specific.

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the operating system or shell. Consider using lower-case names for your own variables, as these are reserved for application use -- to quote [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html): *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*

Comment: (...why does this apply to shell variables, not just explicit environment variables? Glad you asked! Setting a shell variable with the name of an existing environment variable will implicity overwrite the latter; thus, all the folks using `export PATH` are actually doing so needlessly unless `PATH` wasn't in their environment at all beforehand).

Comment: On a different note -- always use NUL-delimited streams for passing filenames around. Your current code can't handle a file with a newline in its name -- that is, something created with `touch $'foo\nbar'`. That's particularly important if you have something like `$'./$\n/etc/passwd\n/hello.aux'` -- you don't want your code to try to delete `/etc/passwd` because it couldn't figure out which newlines were part of the filename, vs which newlines were part of the separator between files.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for con/in-structive comments.

Comment: BTW, there are a bunch of behaviors that happen when `$(...)` is expanded unquoted (that is, without double quotes around it) that are generally undesired -- if you have a command in `$(...)` emit `file name with spaces.txt`, for instance, then it gets split into separate words: `file`, `name`, `with`, and `spaces.txt`, whereas `"$(...)"` is parsed as a single word. The same is true of an array exparsion: `${AUXFILES[@]}` needs to be `"${AUXFILES[@]}"` to accurately return the array's elements regardless of exactly what those contents are.

Comment: That's a bit embarrassing. I copied this from my Makefile and there the expansion does not work when I quote the array. No idea why though...

Comment: For completeness, the vernacular is *process substitution* (e.g. `<(cmd)` ) and *command substitution* (e.g. `$(cmd)`). Yes, *a rose by any other name*, but it may help with further investigating distinctions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a much simpler example which will show you what is happening.

```
$ echo Hello > somefile
$ find . -name somefile
./somefile
$ cat < $(find . -name somefile)
Hello
$ cat < <(find . -name somefile)
./somefile
```

The `$( )` construct just runs the command inside and replaces itself with the command's output.

```
    $ cat < $(find . -name somefile)
```

gets rewritten by bash as:

```
    $ cat < ./somefile
    Hello
```

which feeds the contents of `somefile` into the command `cat`.

The `<( )` construct is a bit trickier.  The command inside of the `<( )` is executed and its results are fed as input to the command.  So this command:

```
    $ cat < <(find . -name somefile)
```

will get interpreted by bash like so:

```
    $ find . -name somefile > /tmp/results
    $ cat < /tmp/results
    ./somefile
```

The actual mechanism in bash is a little more subtle than this.  It doesn't store the results in an actual file; rather, it uses pipes the connect the output of the `find` to the input of `cat`, and runs both commands at the same time (with `cat` reading input as `find` makes it available).